# Using mustache templates as partial views in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mustache

I'm trying to use mustache views in Rails 4 instead of some old partial views that hosted some HTML templates I am sharing with a javascript application.

Added config/initializers/mustache.rb

```
# Tell Rails how to render mustache templates
module MustacheTemplateHandler
  def self.call(template)
    #assigns contains all the instance_variables defined on the controller's view method
    "Mustache.render(#{template.source.inspect}, assigns).html_safe"
  end
end

# Register a mustache handler in the Rails template engine
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:mustache, MustacheTemplateHandler)
```

I named my template `_template.mustache` and put it the template in `views/sales/_template.mustache` and I can render it just fine from normal `.html.erb` with `render partial: 'template'`

Where do I put the `Template.rb` file for it to work with the mustache?

```
class Template < Mustache

  def something
    # return something
    "WOW"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can write this variables directly to yours controller.